# How to import "long" datetime format with weekday in Transact SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, datetime-format

I have a timestamp of the following format: `'Sun, 08 Aug 2016 04:12:01'` and apparently SQL Server dislikes it. As far as I read, [no SQL Server datetime style have weekdays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx). For what it worth, this datetime string comes from JSON of webservice I'm trying to consume and browsers seems to be OK with this format, but unfortunately datetime format is outside JSON standard scope.

Please advise how can I deal with this. Is there a way to tell SQL Server to accept weekday?

Comment: Please show the code that you are using that is failing.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, obviously, it's `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, 'Sun, 08 Aug 2016 04:12:01', 113)`

Comment: Can't you just start from the 6th character?

Comment: @JamesZ, I'm still hoping for more strict and native way, leaving just stripping weekday away or patterns as very last resort.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like below.

```
   SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, RIGHT('Sun, 08 Aug 2016 04:12:01',20))
```